# Git Hub Workflow

Tags: git, workflow

At my work we are developing a new workflow, I'm concerned about merging back into each individual person's branch from the develop branch. Would any issues be caused if each person keeps merging into their individual branches after approved code is merged into develop? Based on how git merges.

```
               (Master)
                  ^
                  |
                (UAT)
                  ^
                  |
(Person C)---->(Develop)<----(Person A)

           <--    ^ |    ---->
                  | V
               (Person B)
```

Each person merges after a develop change is made.
All repositories are remote.

Answer (score 1):

No, merging common code branch into individual branches is OK and common.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this is quite common. Each developer works on his own branch, frequently merging the "develop" branch into his own.

Once he has a feature ready, it will be given to testers, reviewers etc. Once approved, it will be merged into the "develop" branch.

Once this step is done, the "develop" branch has new commits which again other developers would fetch and merge into their branch and thus the process loops!